# How to be able to locally connect to two separate websites that are running on the same IP and same port?

Tags: networking, dns

I don't think this question has been asked yet, and if it has I apologize.

I am currently running two websites on an Apache2 server which are both are on port 80. On Google Domains I have the DNS for the domain of each site pointing to the public IP address of the server, so if I'm outside of local network I can navigate to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or [www.exmple2.com](http://www.exmple2.com) and it will show the appropriate website.

If I'm locally on the network I can't just visit [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or [www.example2.com](http://www.example2.com) because that's point to my public ip. So normally when I want to visit a site locally I'd just navigate to the private ip of the server and it'd show the website, but if that ip has two websites running how do I differentiate between the two? Am I needing to set up a local DNS, and if so how would I go about doing that?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, and thanks ahead of time!

Comment: I don't think so... That guy is using his Ubuntu machine as the router for his home network. Currently any traffic on my LAN is going to my router and then from there. Would I need to set something on my modem that finds www.example.com and www.example2.com requests and sends it to my Ubuntu server which then would need to complete the request?

Comment: In this case, you can redirect those host-names / domain-names requests from your network to the web-server's IP in your router. You might need to add firewall rules in the router as well to specify only requests from your local sub-net.

Comment: Yeah that's perfect! When I was looking under my modem settings I must've been so fried I missed the big ol' LAN DNS host mapping setting. Duh! The only issue now is that if I go to either www.example.com or www.example2.com it's only showing www.example.com... So by chance do you know what I need to edit on the apache server to differentiate the request properly?

Comment: Never mind! It was a slight adjustment, but I got it! Thanks Raffa! Cheers!